# Laravel "return redirect" not working on Heroku

Tags: php, redirect, heroku, laravel-5

I have a larval application I've recently deployed to a Heroku server and set up SSL for.

I have a couple instances of the following code which is called in various functions that should all redirect to the same spot. All the code in the related functions preceding it executes correctly.

```
return redirect('/cart');
```

Locally, this works as intended, but on heroku it returns www.site.com/index.php

Accessing the the url /cart works correctly when not using "redirect".

I've checked the error logs on heroku and they don't show anything particularly helpful, just a request to the route that later returns the redirect.

Comment: Have you tried setting cart as a named route so yo can do `return redirect()->route('cart');` ? Maybe that could work

Comment: @egvaldes I attempted to do that and it ends up the same; sends me to index.php.